# How to create soap service in zf2?

Tags: soap, wsdl, zend-framework2

I have a table named 'Restaurant' with following fields:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `restaurant` (
  `restaurant_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT,
  `restaurant_id_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT ,
  `restaurant_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT,
  `restaurant_score` int(10) NOT NULL,
   ....
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=95 ;
```

I need to utilize the SOAP server using the ZF2 component `Zend\Soap\Server` using WSDL for concrete entity/mapper/model(ex Restaurant)(insert/update/delete/retrieve).

Yes I have read the documentation, but I haven't searched for more examples on how to  develop a SOAP server in module(Controller\View\Model). If you have any concrete examples or detailed explanations using instances of `Zend\Soap\Server` and/or `Zend\Soap\Client` I would be appreciative of reviewing those to help me out.

Comment: In this post you can see how to build a soap server:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111209/zend-framework-2-soap-server-wsdl-failed-to-load